# How can I keep the DDL for my Trigger in Harmony with my Trigger code?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a Trigger in Database Workbench (Lite, for MySQL) with this:

```
delimiter // 
CREATE TRIGGER employeesTableInsert AFTER INSERT ON EMPLOYEES FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; END IF;//
```

When I try to create the new Trigger, though, I get this err msg:

[image]

This seems odd; I look at the DDL tab in Database Workbench, and it has this:

[image]

Why is it doubling and mangling my Trigger code there in the (read-only) DDL?

As shown at the outset, my Trigger code only contains what is shown above:

[image]

So is the problem with my code, or is it because the DDL tab is confused? Or is my code CAUSING the DDL tab to become confused, or what?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update only the value you need following.

you can't use SET without a BEGIN and END, it is not a query.

I am wondering why there is a END IF in your code

Edit i also changed your TRIGGER to BEFORE INSERT, because on there you can change the values of a NEW column (see   Bill Karwin comment)

And actually you don't need a trigger see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER employeesTableInsert BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEES 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.CREATED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END//
```

Comment: Also you can't change any column (e.g. `NEW.created`) in an `AFTER` trigger.